# fseek() sets the pointer to wrong position

Tags: c++, fgets, fseek, ftell

I have a .dat file with the following structure:

```
Object name | Area | Length |Form Factor
```

I am trying the find which object has the minimum area. I read the whole file and keep track of the object with the minimum area, and its position with ftell(). When I am done reading the file I set stream position indicator to whatever I get from ftell(). Then I read that line as my final result, but right now, I am reading the wrong line.

objects.dat:

```
toy1 12785.00 550.70 23.22
toy2 11506.50 495.63 0.48
Pen 35008.65 1450.98 0.17
Pencil 42788.35 1773.42 0.209
card7 128433.00 1552.67 0.67
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *cfPtr;
    errno_t err;

    char name[15];
    double area, length, fF;
    double minArea = 100000.0;
    long address, minAreaAdd;

    char string[100];

    if ((err = fopen_s(&cfPtr, "objects.dat", "r")) != 0)   // Check if we can reach the file
        printf("The file 'objecs.dat' was not opened to read.\n");
    else
    {
        while (fgets(string, 100, cfPtr)) 
        {
            address = ftell(cfPtr);
            sscanf_s(string,"%s %lf %lf %lf", &name, sizeof name, &area, &length, &fF);

            if (area < minArea)
            {
                minArea = area;
                minAreaAdd = address;
            }
        }

        cout << "Min Area: " << minArea << " Address: " << minAreaAdd << "\n\n";

        fseek(cfPtr, minAreaAdd, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(string, 100, cfPtr);
        sscanf_s(string, "%s %lf %lf %lf", &name, sizeof name, &area, &length, &fF);

        cout << "Name: " << name << " Area : " << area << " Length: " << length << " Form factor: " << fF << "\n";

        fclose(cfPtr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Min Area: 11506.5 Address: 55

Name: Pen Area : 35008.7 Length: 1450.98 Form factor: 0.17
```

Comment: `fseek()` is working fine, its your logic that is all wrong.

Comment: Similarly, so is tagging as C *and* C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by "1201ProgramAlarm", you are getting the address after you have read the line you want to save. That is, you use `ftell` after `fgets`.

What happens is that `fgets` moves the file position indicator while reading the data. This is because `fgets` needs to prepare the file for the next read operation, otherwise you would be stuck at the same position, reading the same data.

You need to reverse this logic. Here goes one example:

```
address = -1
do
{
    if (address >= 0) {
        sscanf_s(string,"%s %lf %lf %lf", &name, sizeof name, &area, &length, &fF);

        if (area < minArea)
        {
            minArea = area;
            minAreaAdd = address;
        }
    }
    address = ftell(cfPtr);
} while (ret = fgets(string, 100, cfPtr));
```

Comment: `while (address = ftell(cfPtr), fgets(string, 100, cfPtr)) { ... }` seems less cluttered to me...

Comment: That's great, thanks. Shouldn't the if condition be if (address >= 0) ? Otherwise, it would skip the first line which starts at position 0, I believe.

Comment: Yep, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I agree, rici, I would have done it that way too, but it just seam less didactic.

Answer (score 3):

When you get the file position and store it into `address`, that's after you've read the line in, so when you seek to it to get the answer you'll get the line *after* the correct one.